# What's the best way to add a copy of a list in another list?

Tags: c#, list, copy

I tried to add naively a list in another but I loose the data when I clear this first list.

```
        List<List<string>> lls = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();

        ls.Add("a");
        ls.Add("b");
        ls.Add("c");

        lls.Add(ls);
        ls.Clear(); 

        foreach (List<string> lst in lls)
            foreach (string s in lst)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); // Display nothing
```

So I tried to "copy" my `List<string>` in the other list but I don't really know how to simply and properly do this. What's the best way to copy data in a list ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new list with the same items:

```
new List<string>(ls)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>(lls);
```

Comment: Yes it will. It'll effectively copy the references to the items contained in `lls`, not a reference to `lls` itself.